# How to display alert dialog when screen is off?

Tags: android, screen, android-alertdialog

I want to display an Alert-dialog. But did not display when device screen is turning off. Now , how can i to force the screen to turning on when show an Alert-dialog?

Comment: see `android.os.PowerManager`

Comment: what is your opinion about : dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON). is this a solution ?

Comment: not work on real device

Comment: do you know AVD? AVD is Android Virtual Device , in android simulator work as well. but in real android device not worked. thats my mistake